# Javascript: add year to the current timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

i'm looking to handle a script wich has to add 10 years to the current timestamp in javascript...

But when i try this:

```js
Date.now() + /* 10 years in seconds */ 315569520
```

It doens't work...
Is there anyway to implement it ?

Comment: 10 years in miliseconds is 315569259747 MS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use a Date constructor to create the date from the value you calculated.

```
new Date(Date.now() + 315569520 * 1000)
```

You need to add the value of 10 years in **milliseconds**, and then pass the new value to a Date **constructor**

Comment: The milliseconds in 10 years depends on the years in question as there may be one, two or three leap years involved.

Answer (score 1):

Do like:

```js
const dt = new Date;
dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear()+10);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

plz check this url. You can find your solution.
https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-41.php

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple you can achieve in two line code:

`let timestamp  = new Date();

timestamp.setFullYear(timestamp.getFullYear() + 10);
console.log(timestamp);`